# Using strong params when assigning model attributes in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, strong-parameters

Hi i'm running into an issue with my code where i'm not sure where to use strong params. In this case I have a document object being set with a mix of preset values and values coming from my form for example.

```
class DocumentsController < ApplicationController
 def add_document
  document_name = params[:document_name]
  document_parent_id = params[:doc_parent_id]

  @document = Document.new(name: document_name, parent_id: document_parent_id, document_owner_id: current_user_id, created_by: current_user.name)
  @document.save
   #do flash stuff here
 end
```

So the form is only submitting the document name and document parent id through the params hash. Should these two values be whitelisted using strong params? And If so how can I use strong params to create the new document with the other values that aren't coming from my form.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1/ Yes it should be whitelisted.

```
def add_document
  # stuff
  @document = Document.new(document_params.merge(
    document_owner_id: current_user_id, 
    created_by: current_user.name
  ))
  # stuff
end

def document_params
  params.require(:document).permit(:name, :parent_id)
end
```

2/ To submit not from form, you just need to submit nested attribute `document` inside params alongside with other params:

```
{ document: { name: '<Name>', parent_id: '<Id>' }, other_params: '...' }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class DocumentsController < ApplicationController
  def add_document
    @document = Document.new document_params.merge(document_owner_id: current_user_id, created_by: current_user.name)
    @document.save
  end

  private

  def document_params
    params.permit(:document_name, :doc_parent_id)
  end 

end
```

---

Your code really could do with improving a lot.

Firstly, Rails 4+ convention is to have a "top level" param value of the model (in your case `document`):

```
params: {
   document: {
      document_name: "x",
      doc_parent_id: "y"
   }
}
```

This would allow you to call the strong params method properly:

```
def document_params
   params.require(:document).permit(:document_name, :doc_parent_id)
end
```

The way to achieve this is to use `form_for` (which should be used in conjunction with a RESTful controller):

```
#app/views/documents/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @document do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :document_name %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

#app/controllers/documents_controller.rb
class DocumentsController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @document = Document.new
   end

   def create
      @document = Document.new document_params
      @document.save
   end
end
```

--

Finally, you also need to make sure your model attribute names work well.

You're currently using `document_name` as an attribute name. If it were my application, I'd call it `name`, allowing you to call `@document.name` in the future.

The same for your other attributes:

```
document_name -> "name"
doc_parent_id -> "parent_id"
document_owner_id -> "owner_id"
```